# After adding MathView Library my recyclerview Steal works

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

When i add `MathView` library my `recyclerView` make a Steal scroll. Before add MathView my `recyclerview` working smooth and fast but when i add `MathView` Library its working slow and Stealing.

I used this Library for `MathView` :- `implementation 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'`

`MathView` Library Link :-https://github.com/kexanie/MathView

Comment: `MathView` is a `WebView` . And i think it should not placed inside `RecyclerView`. If you are placing it you need to wrap the content and make `MathView` non scrollable .

Comment: but i want to use MathView in recyclerview , can you help me , How can i smooth my recyclerview with using MathView? @ADM

Comment: You need to make some changes to `onTouch` inside `MathView`. Just Search `WebView inside ListView` and follow.